# Aggregate Pipeline to exclude collections from db.watch() MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, aggregate, pipeline, changestream

I am using MongoDB's changeStreams to watch for changes in my database. I'd like to watch every collection for changes except two. Something like this:

```
const pipeline = [{ $match: { name: { $ne: "excludedCollection1" } } }, 
    { $match: { name: { $ne: "excludedCollection2" } } }];
const db = client.db("myDatabase");
const changeStream = db.watch(pipeline);
```

However, this code does not exclude the two collections.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot filter out collections via collection name from the piepline itself. According to mongo's [manual](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/method/db.watch/), `pipeline` is used to "Specify a pipeline to filter/modify the change events **output**". If you notice within your [change events](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/change-events/), there is an `ns` property that gives the namespace of the change. You can use your pipeline to exclude matches of this ns property:

```
  const pipeline = [
  {
    $match: {
      $and: [
        {
          ns: {
            $ne: {
              db: "myDatabase",
              coll: "notifications",
            },
          },
        },
        {
          ns: {
            $ne: {
              db: "myDatabase",
              coll: "rules",
            },
          },
        },
      ],
    },
  },
];
const db = client.db("myDatabase");
const changeStream = db.watch(pipeline);
```